# make html5 canvas full page with jquery

Tags: html, canvas

I tried to make the html canvas fullpage. In my code it alerts that, the canvas size = window size, but it's not showing the correct output.

Here's the html ->

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the css ->

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
}
canvas
{
    /*border: 1px solid black;*/
    background: green;
}
```

and jquery ->

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.fn.showMSG = function(){
        var canvas = $("canvas");

        var canvasWidth = canvas.width();
        var canvasHeight = canvas.height();
        var windowWidth = $(window).width();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        canvasWidth = windowWidth;
        canvasHeight = windowHeight;

        var txt = "";
        txt += "Canvas width/height: " + canvasWidth;
        txt += "x" + canvasHeight + "\n";
        txt += "Window width/height: " + windowWidth;
        txt += "x" + windowHeight;
        alert(txt);
    }

    $(window).ready(function(){
        $.fn.showMSG();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix your code. Let me explain.
Sooo, since `width()` and `height()` seemed to me like set/get functions, I tried doing these:

```
canvas.width(windowWidth);
canvas.height(windowHeight);
```

instead of (what you did):

```
canvasWidth = windowWidth;
canvasHeight = windowHeight;
```

And it worked. Try it out!

Comment: it worked fine...but why the horizontal scrollbar is appearing ?

Comment: I didn't get any horizontal scrollbar [here](https://i.imgur.com/8vBexaO.png). I tried removing `margin: 0;` from the css and that gave me the horizontal scrollbar. Did you change anything on your css file?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea anymore on why you're getting a horizontal scrollbar. I'm still not that experienced with these. Hope you get it fixed!